# Can't transform geometry to geojson

Tags: python, flask, geoalchemy2

My problem is this. I'm creating a model for some data.

```
class Cables(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'cables'

    id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    route = Column(Geometry(geometry_type='LINESTRING', srid=4326), nullable=False)
```

Now, I want to transform such a route to GeoJSON.

Things I've tried

```
@app.route("/api/cable/<int:id>", methods=['GET'])
def get_cable(id):
    cable = session.query(Cables).filter(Cables.id == id).first()
    return str(geoalchemy2.functions.ST_AsGeoJSON(cable.route))
```

returns `ST_AsGeoJSON(ST_GeomFromEWKB(:ST_GeomFromEWKB_1))`

If I change the return:

```
return geoalchemy2.functions.ST_AsGeoJSON(cable.route)
```

returns `TypeError: 'ST_AsGeoJSON' object is not callable`

```
return str(cable.route)
```

returns `0102000020e610000002000000b34fd4d9bca351c032e14d5134c240c0d24f8055e0a351c0dedea9f4dcbf40c0`
This would signal that I do have a geometry object.

```
return cable.route
```

returns `TypeError: 'WKBElement' object is not callable`

If I print the route type,

```
print(type(cable.route))
```

returns

```
<class 'geoalchemy2.elements.WKBElement'>
```

I thought it should have returned an object of such class, and not the class itself. I'm baffled at this point and I don't know what I should do now.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6):

It seems to be that the correct way to call ST_AsGeoJSON is inside a query.
For instance,

```
ruta = session.query(Cables.route.ST_AsGeoJSON()).filter(Cables.id == id).first()
```

What I ended up doing was installing a new library (shapely) in order to read the hex bytestring and then transform it to a dictionary, as dictionaries can be transformed to json in an easy way.

```
def ewkb_route_to_dict(self):
    """
    returns the cable's route as a dictionary.
    It uses shapely.wkb.loads. The first argument is the route as a bytestring,
    and the second one (True) is to tell loads that
    the input wkb will be represented as a hex string
    """
    return mapping(shapely.wkb.loads(str(self.route), True))
```

Then in my to string method:

```
def __str__(self):
    d = dict()
    ...
    d["route"] = self.ewkb_route_to_dict()
    ...
    return dumps(d)
```

That will correctly transform the geometry to GeoJSON.

Comment: Is it possible to return a name or ID with the geometry? I'm struggling with a similar issue; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297713/geojson-feature-collection

Answer (score 2):

I know that this post is old but for those who still have this difficulty it follows my solution:

```
import ast
from flask.json import jsonify
from sqlalchemy import func

@app.route("/api/cable/<int:id>", methods=['GET'])
def get_cable(id):
    geom = session.query(func.ST_AsGeoJSON(Cables.route)).filter(Cables.id == id).scalar()
    # The code below makes a geojson with CRS.
    # See http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html for more details.
    #geom = session.query(func.ST_AsGeoJSON(Cables.route,15,2)).filter(Cables.id == id).scalar()
    return jsonify(ast.literal_eval(geom))
```

Comment: Is it possible to return a name or ID with the geometry? I'm struggling with a similar issue; https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/297713/geojson-feature-collection

Comment: the `scalar()` will return the first column of the first row, if you want other columns you can use `all()` instead, but in this case will return a list of rows.

`session.query(Cables.id, Cables.other_data, func.ST_AsGeoJSON(Cables.route)).filter(Cables.id == id).all()`

Comment: Results are displaying in the console, with 500 internal server error at URL. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you paste the exception description?

Answer (score 1):

[In the docs](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html), PostGIS helpfully informs you that:

> `ST_AsGeoJSON` only builds geometry. You need to build the rest of Feature from your Postgres table yourself

Indeed, trying to send the output of `ST_AsGeoJSON` to a Leaflet layer will fail because it won't be a valid `Feature`. While the docs provide 25 lines of PostGIS code, using it with SQLAlchemy is unappealing. The easiest way I've found to do this is using a small python library, [`shapely-geojson`](https://pypi.org/project/shapely-geojson/).

```
$ pip install shapely-geojson
```

And then in your code:

```
from shapely_geojson import dumps, Feature
from geoalchemy2.shape import to_shape

cable = session.query(Cables).filter(Cables.id == id).first()
feature = Feature(to_shape(cable[0]))
geoJSON = dumps(feature)
```

Note that the GeoJSON standard changed in 2016 to enforce the [right hand rule](http://mapster.me/right-hand-rule-geojson-fixer/). Depending on how your line or polygon is structured in your data, and how persnickety the receiving software is, you may need to use [`geojson_rewind`](https://pypi.org/project/geojson-rewind/) to change the order of the points.