# Return valid GeoJSON with Flask + GeoAlchemy2 app

Tags: json, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, geoalchemy2

Since few days I am wondering how to make my Flask app return valid GeoJSON, here is what I got so far:

`models.py`

```
class Building(base):

    __tablename__ = 'buildings'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    district = Column(Unicode)
    address = Column(Unicode)
    name = Column(Unicode)
    building_type = Column(Unicode)
    mpoly = Column(Geometry('MULTIPOLYGON'))

    building = relationship("User")


# this part is done as answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684512/cant-transform-geometry-to-geojson
    def building_to_dict(self):
        return mapping(shapely.wkb.loads(str(self.mpoly), True))
    
    def __str__(self):
        d = dict()
        d["id"] = self.id
        d["district"] = self.district
        d["address"] = self.address
        d["name"] = self.name
        d["building_type"] = self.building_type
        d["mpoly"] = self.building_to_dict()
        return shapely.dumps(d)
```

Now at main file I have following routing:

`app.py`

```
@app.route('/geojson')
def get_json():
    features = session.query(Building.mpoly.ST_AsGeoJSON()).all()
    return jsonify(features)
```

And here are my two problems:

1)
Returned JSON-like response that looks like following:
`"{\"type\":\"MultiPolygon\",\"coordinates\":[[[[16.8933137,52.471446],...,]]]}"`
Is not proper GeoJSON.
Features variable before jsonify looks this way:
`[('{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[16.914159616,52.473822807],...,]]]}',)]`

2)
How my GeoAlchemy query should look like, to return not just geometry field, but others as well?

Any kind of hints or helps highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: So I do not know the exact solution, but I think your Question is related to the following links. (1) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7907596/json-dumps-vs-flask-jsonify . (2) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102754/jsonify-a-sqlalchemy-result-set-in-flask .
According to the comment in 1 flask jsonify "...does not turn SQLAlchemy objects and lists into JSON."
So I believe what you might need to do is write a function or class that serializes the database object(features) , and then pass it to return jsonify(features).

Comment: [('{"type":"MultiPolygon","coordinates":[[[[16.914159616,52.473822807],...,]]]}',)]   <-- That does not look like a json, but more like a set holding a string inside a list.. So look into serializing transforming that data into json.

This is what pure GeoJson structure looks like   :

{
  "type": "Feature",
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [125.6, 10.1]
  },
  "properties": {
    "name": "Dinagat Islands"
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

You may use [marshmallow-sqlalchemy](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for creating json like responses.

create
`schemas.py`

```
    #!schemas.py
    from marshmallow import fields
    from marshmallow_sqlalchemy import ModelSchema
    from app.models import Building
    from geoalchemy.shape import to_shape


    class BuildingSchema(ModelSchema):
        id = fields.Integer()
        district = fileds.Unicode()
        address = fileds.Unicode()
        name = fields.Unicode()
        building_type = fields.Unicode()
        mpoly = fileds.Method("geom_to_json")
    
        @staticmethod
        def geom_to_json(obj):
            mpoly = to_shape(obj.mpoly)
            return {
                    lat: mpoly.y,
                    lon: mpoly.x,
                    #and so on ... 
                    } 
        
        class Meta:
            model = Building
            exclude = ("mpoly")
            

    bulding_schema = BuildingSchema(many=True)
```

after this you can use it in your views(routes)

```
    from app.schemas import building_schema 


    @app.route('/geojson')
    def json():
        buildings = Buildings.query.all()
        response = building_schema.dumps(buildings)
        
        return response
```